# VC++ solution with parts of the DLLs defined as Windows app store and part not

Tags: visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps

I have a solution in Visual C++ 2013, with ~20 projects and several DLL ones among them. So far all DLLs were not defined as Windows-Store-App, which is perfect for me (local use only). But now, when I try to create  another DLL and EXE projects in that solution, the DLL is automatically defined as Win8.1 and Windows-Store-App-Support - I couldn't find any way to avoid it. The EXE loads both kinds of DLLs - the new and some of the old ones. I guess it is this incompatibility that results in a crash inside ntdll. 
How can I continue with the same kind of projects I already have? Opening a new solution and porting everything will consume ~ a full week of work.